How I can pass the initialization config into my service worker?
I am making a library that initializes a firebase push notification. I want to achienve a hassle-free firebase configuration by letting the js to set it up for me.
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, onMessage, getToken, isSupported } from "firebase/messaging";


function tokenHandle(currentToken,url) {
    if (currentToken) {
        console.log(currentToken);
    }
}

function uponGrantedPermissionHandler(messaging,vapidKey,serviceWorkerUrl,tokenNotificationUrl,workerAsModule){
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        const workerConfig = workerAsModule?{ type: 'module' }:undefined
        
        serviceWorkerUrl = serviceWorkerUrl??"https://mycdn.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js";

        navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(serviceWorkerUrl, workerConfig)
        .then((registration) => {
                console.log(messaging)
                if (registration) {
                    console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope)
                    getToken(messaging, { vapidKey })
                        .then((token)=>tokenHandle(token,tokenNotificationUrl))
                        .catch(error => console.error(error));
                }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err)
            })
    }
}

function pushNotificationInit(firebaseConfig,vapidKey,tokenNotificationUrl,serviceWorkerUrl,workerAsModule){
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    isSupported().then((isSupported) => {
        
        if (!isSupported) {
            throw "Browser Is not Supported"
            return;
        }

        const messaging = getMessaging(app)


        Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
            console.log('permiss', permission)

            if (permission === 'granted') {
                uponGrantedPermissionHandler(messaging,vapidKey,serviceWorkerUrl,tokenNotificationUrl,workerAsModule)

                onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
                    const n = new Notification(payload.notification.title, {
                        body: payload.notification.body,
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }).catch((error)=>console.error(error));
}


export {pushNotificationInit};


what I want to do is to have an easy api to use and be as simple as:
import {pushNotificationInit} from './firebaseLib';

pushNotificationInit(firebaseConfig,vapidKey,"",null,true)

And pushNotificationInit to initialize the worker as well. But a common service worker for firebase is:

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { onBackgroundMessage,getMessaging } from 'firebase/messaging/sw'

const firebaseConfig = {
  // config
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    
    // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background message body',
    icon: 'icon.png'
  };
    
  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});


What I want to do is to pass the config from core js into my service worker. Is there a way to do that?

Whats the problem/does not work? I see no "real problem" in your question beside that "i want to ...".
